# How to Filter RadGridItems from radgrid.Items collection?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm developing using Telerik Controls for ASP.NET AJAX and working with RadGrid's ItemCommand event. I need to filter / select specific items(or rows) from grid.Items collection?

Here's my markup for button in RadGrid.

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn runat="server" Text="Fill Days" ImageUrl="images/16/disk_blue.png" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="FillDays" HeaderTooltip="Fill for this day" />
```

And the code behind:

```
Protected Sub myDatagrid_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles myDatagrid.ItemCommand

'as i have lots of rows in table, i don't want to loop through all items.

For Each gridDataItem As GridDataItem In myDatagrid.Items

Next

End Sub
```

How do i do filter these grid items, so that i have specific items with specific column value?

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in C# but the idea is the same. You have to specify on MasteTable DataKeyName you use to for indexing your table.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" Culture="cs-CZ">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Default"/>
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="Id" Visible="false">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" CommandName="Apply">
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                ...
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Then use this index:

```
protected void RgFiltry_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var filterId = (int)e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Id"];

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Apply":
                Apply(filterId);
                break;
            case "Default":
                SaveDefault(filterId);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer allows to find the specific Item's data e.g. like Id by using DataKeyValues. I don't want to get this, I need to select certain items from myDatagrid.Items collection, e.g. if it has ten items, i need to select 5 items out of it.

Comment: Hmm, so I'm afraid I'll not be able to help you. If you need to keep data in grid you have to loop through them. But if you want to use for example Grid Paging I think that myDatagrid.Items will return only active page...